# How to determine the required CPU speed for a micro-controller with a 2-phase encoder attached to interrupts?

Tags: microcontroller, quadrature-encoder, steering

I am building a high-torque steering servo. I am trying to use the Adafruit Feather M0, which has a CPU speed of 48MHz, to monitor a 2-phase encoder that has 2400 pulses per rotation. I have attached the encoder's 2 signal wires to interrupt pins on the Feather M0.  I have it almost working, but sometimes it just stops responding or has a very delayed response.  I have a suspicion that I'm overloading the CPU.  There are some other factors at play, in addition to the encoder signals.  I am also using serial communication to report the position information.

I am trying to get a grasp on determining the required micro-controller CPU speed for my project.

Comment: Its a 2 phase-encoder, meaning it has 2 signal outputs; phase A and phase B.  This allows the microcontroller to determine the direction of rotation.  I thought that was fairly clearly explained in my OP.

Comment: you only need one interrupt ... the state of the two pins at the interrupt event determine the direction of rotation ... do you have any specific reason for using two interrupts?

Comment: I think I see what you mean now.  I'm sorry for being suspicious of your comment.  I've seen some people just trying to get points by posting answers without clearly considering the OPs problem.  I will try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: no need to apologize ... i understand your concern about answers ... i do not think that points are collected for comments

Comment: I remove the second interrupt attachment and I'm sure that will help, but I'm still having the same issues.  I don't know for sure, but it seems like the board is crashing while monitoring the encoder.  All of a sudden the position value is reset back to zero.  I have some logic that does reset the counter if it goes past the max pulses per rotation, but it doesn't ever appear to get to that point before resetting.

Comment: *Edit*: *removed

Comment: So, I had some logic for a reset button that when clicked resets the counter.  As a shot in the dark, I removed that logic and somehow that seemed to fix it.  I need to do some more testing to be sure, but I think that might have been it.  Thanks for your help anyways!